# C Programming, getch() not work in IDE Netbean?

Tags: c, netbeans, getch

My C labs project have to run in Netbeans on Windows 7, using main file C.
The Requirement asked that input any key to continue.

In DevC I can use `getch()` to solve this, but in Netbeans it shows the erorr that the function is identifiers.
My question is :
1. Which function I can use to do this case ?
2. Should I use got to do this?

Comment: @Haris But this requires the user to hit the enter key

Comment: @Vu VAnh is the requirement to input *any* key to continue or is Haris solution fine too ? Also, on what OS do you use netbeans ? Windows ? Linux ? ...

Comment: @mikedu95 I'm using windows7. The solution of Haris is not work as I tried it recently. The requirement is "the program should ask users to input any key to repeat..."

Comment: @VuVAnh so getch should do it. You can already try _getch (new MS name) instead of getch (legacy DOS name), but if that still doesn't fix it, post a very short complete code that shows that it doesn't work, and post the full error message too.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such standrad function `getch`. Maybe you want `getchar` or `getc`.

Comment: :The UI show " Press any key to continue." and wait at that. I have to input any key  to do furthur function but the inputted key doesn't not allow to show in UI.

Answer (score 1):

if your c lab is on linux os, then this code may help

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <termios.h>


/*
    warning:
    error handling was ommited for clarity.
    check [tcgetattr, tcsetattr ] documentation

*/


int getch(){

    int                 ret;
    struct termios      back;
    struct termios      tmp;
    int fd =            0;      //stdin

    tcgetattr(fd, &back);       // a backup
    tcgetattr(fd, &tmp);

    // code get from man page
    tmp.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP
                   | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
    tmp.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
    tmp.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);

    tmp.c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB);
    tmp.c_cflag |= CS8;
    // endof man page

    // apply configuration
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tmp);

    ret=getchar();

    // reset back the configuration
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &back);

    return ret;
}



int main(){

   int ret;
    printf("Press a key:");
    ret=ret= getch();
    printf("%c\n",ret);
    printf("DONE\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As show in the link bellow the correct function is `getchar`. 
If instead you're using GCC (with netbeans) then it is `getc`.

As I could see see, both are thread safe and blocking.

[MSDN getchar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x198c66c.aspx)

[Linux getc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getc)